# XML parsing returned from a URL query

Tags: php, javascript, xml, http, rest

I am working on LinkedIn APIs where I make a query using URL. The result of the query is returned in XML and I need to display it to the user. Does simplexml_load_file() call supports this fetching from a URL? I tried using it but it hangs up!

Is there any better method to parse XML returned from a query other than simplexml_load_file?

Answer (score 0):

Use `XMLReader`, look here: [XMLReader](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php).